# In C, How do I add a Node to the start of a List?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, malloc, nodes

I have been trying to figure out how to add a node to the start of a list but I cant seem to make it work, I've wrote comments through out my code explaining what im having trouble with, I cant find any good tutorials that work for me as I keep getting errors, I have a fair understanding of what going o but haven't figured it out yet.

Heres my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
}

void addToStart(struct node **head);

int main(){

int choice;

// This is how you initialize nodes, right?
struct node *head = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );
struct node *listPtr;;

head->data= 0;
head->next = NULL;

listPtr = head;

printf("Pick one of the following:\n");
printf("1) add node to start\n");
printf("2) add node to end\n");
printf("3) display all nodes\n");
printf("4) display length\n");
printf("5) search list\n");

scanf("%d", choice);

switch(choice){
case 1:
    addToStart();
    break;
}
}

/* This is ment to be a funct to add a node to the start? I got it from my
 college notes but not sure if im using it right, am I ment to pass 
 something through it? if so what? */
void addToStart (struct node **head)
{
struct node *newNode;
newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
printf("\nEnter data for this node");
scanf("%d", &newNode->data);

/*What is happening in these 2 lines below? it looks confusing and makes me
feel like im doing the same thing twice, from what I understand we are  giving      the next in the node newNode the address of head,
the starting node, but then we
point head to new node? wut?*/
newNode->next = *head;
*head = newNode; // transfer the address of newNode' to 'head'
}
```

Comment: when you insert a node first, the old head becomes head->next, and the new node becomes the new head

Comment: `addToStart` is to be called with `&head`

Comment: the last line "*head = newNode;" is probably most confusing - what it does is that it changes where the pointer points in the memory..the previous address of the head will be changed - reassigned onto the new address - address of the newNode (which is the head from now on)

Comment: Its always a good thing to make a drawing of this, http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~srollins/courses/cs112-f07/web/notes/linkedlists/ll2.gif try to visualize what you are trying to do and things become much more clear (imho)

Answer (score 0):

head is pointing to the first node in the list. Therefore, it gets the address of the new allocated node. The other line connects the previous-first node to be the second one (next of head).

You should initialize the list only by setting the list pointer to NULL. Then all you have to do is to use your function to add nodes.

```
struct node *head = NULL;
addToStart(&head);
head->data = 42; // assuming you want to assign 42 in the first node
```

Comment: Why set it to null? I thought using malloc was ment to me a massive part of using nodes for allocating memory?    struct node *head = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof(struct node) );

Comment: null is used as a marker, to denote where the list ends

Comment: You should strive for code reuse. Notice that the code allocating node for initialization it the same as the the one inside addToStart(), so why not to use it? (this flow is much more simpler too)

Answer (score 0):

Well you want to add a new node at the beginning of your list, which means, you have to create a new node, and assign the node at the beginning of your list (first node of your list - head) as a next node of the new node you have just created..

The head of the list is the first node of the list - as you have to able to obtain the node from the memory, and then you can loop through the nodes as each node points to another node..until you find a node which doesn't point to any node (node->next == NULL)- which is the end of the list..

more difficult would be, if you had to insert the node neither at the beginning nor at the end of your list... imagine you have  a list of ten nodes already and you need to insert the node to be the fifth node in the list..in that case, you would have to create a new node, you would assign the fifth node of you node's list as the next node of the newly created node (because your newly created node has to be on the 5th place in the list, therefore the former 5th node would become 6th node), and you would have to repoint the 4th node of your node's list to point to the newly created node as it's next node..

I know it's a bit confusing, can remember me struggling with this at the beginning of the uni studies...

Answer (score 0):

(C++ style, but change new to malloc as appropriate)

```
// head points to the first node in the list
head = new Node(value, head);
// now head points to a new Node whose next pointer is the node which head pointed to before
```

C-style:

```
Node* newNode = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->value = val;
newNode->next = head;
head = newNode;
```

Comment: this question has been tagged in `C`. if you know it's improper, why don't you change it to malloc btw for op?

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
node * head;
node * newnode;
    /* ... */
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node->data = ... ;
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
```